# Insulators and capacitors for a magnetic pulse welding coil

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm trying to design a magnetic pulse welding (MPW) machine to weld 2 tubes together by collapsing an outer tube onto an inner piece. I'm have trouble determining the proper materials for the coil and the capacitors needed.

I intend to machine a disc coil using aluminum for the coil itself but I'm not sure what insulator to use.A similar coil is shown in the picture below where the yellow discs would be the insulator discs and the gray being the metal discs. The metal discs are connected through gap in the insulators so that the metal forms a continuous coil.

The idea of this MPW machine is to discharge a very strong current pulse (roughly 50kA for less than 100ns) through capacitor bank that passes through a coil to create a magnetic field inside the coil that can compress a metal tube that is inside.

For my application I need to achieve a magnetic pressure of roughly 40000 PSI. I know, that's a lot...I need a magnetic field of nearly 40 Tesla. I currently only have access to a 1.1kV power supply to charge the capacitor bank but I may be able to get a larger power supply.

My main questions are would a simple polymer that has high strength and heat rating work as a good insulator for the coil? Do I need to worry about any capacitance produced? I don't thing I do since it is a coil and the insulator is just there so the coil can be bolted together to improve the structural strength.

Also I'm still not sure of what type of capacitors to use. I'm assuming that I will have to charge a bank of capacitors in parallel and discharge them in series because of my limited power supply of 1.1kV but if anyone has any suggestions on a better idea that would be much appreciated!

[image]